# access previous row when using apply on dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I have a large `data.frame` which i would like to run a test on to see if each row in a particular column is equal to the previous row in that column plus some increment.  The data in the column in question is of class `POSIXct`.  I am using a `for` loop but this is very slow so I would like to write the code using the `apply` function.  Here is what i have

```
for (i in 2:100) {
     test$test[i] <- test$date[i-1]+0.5*60*60 == test$date[i]
 }
```

the `data.frame` may be created as so

```
test <- 
    data.frame(date = c(seq(from = Sys.time(), length.out = 100, by = "30 min")), 
               test = c(rep(0,100))
              )
```

How might I translate this into an `apply` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `diff` to calculate the differences. No `apply` or `for` needed.

```
test$test = c(NA, as.double(diff(test$date), units = "mins") == 30)
```

We can convert the difftime units, so we don't need `0.5 * 60 * 60`.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `NA` here?

Comment: @VictorMaxwell I have `NA` for the same reason your loop starts at 2. With `n` numbers, there are `n - 1` differences, so we need to pad the result for it to have the same length.

Comment: @Gregor Just to clarify.  Does `diff` use the `units`. e.g. ` v1 <- Sys.time() + c(1, 10, 100, 200); diff(v1, units = 'mins')
Time differences in secs#
[1]   9  90 100` with `difftime` it is `difftime(v1[-1], v1[-length(v1)], units = 'mins')#
Time differences in mins
[1] 0.150000 1.500000 1.666667`. I am using `R 3.6.0` in case there is any change in behavior

Comment: Huh - turns out it does not. See edits @VictorMaxwell, thanks akrun!

Answer (score 1):

You can also shift the rows and compare

```
test$test[2:nrow(test)] <- (test$date[1:(nrow(test) - 1)] + 0.5*60*60) == 
                            test$date[2:nrow(test)]
```